# Div tags cause other tags to shift position

Tags: html, formatting, dreamweaver

I'm working on my final project in a Dreamweaver class and apparently I didn't have as good a grasp on Div tags as I thought I did.  I have a page with 4 div tags.  One is a container measuring 1280 x 720.  The second div is the menu which is 1280 x 60 px and is relatively positioned to 670 px from the top which places it at the bottom of the page.  The next two tags are aligned left and right.  When I added the left div the menu shifted way down the page.
I'm a little desperate for help so if anyone can help out I'd appreciate it.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-color: #000;
}
#container {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-image: url(images/mushuonlog.jpg);
}
#navigation ul li {
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#navigation ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 display: block;
 font-family: abril-fatface;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top: thick solid rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
}
#navigation ul {
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;

}
#navigation {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
 top: 670px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 51.30%,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 100%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 51.30%,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 51.30%,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 51.30%,rgba(0,0,0,1.00) 100%);
}
#sidebar {
 width: 300px;
 height: 600px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 48.70%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 48.70%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 48.70%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 48.70%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}
#sidebar p {
 color: #DFDFDF;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
#sidebar h1 {
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-family: abril-fatface;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 35px;
}
#navigation a:hover {
 border-top: thick solid #8B4513;
}
#container-housing {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-image: url(images/terrarium.jpg);
}
#container #logo {
 width: 156px;
 height: 178px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -2px;
 top: -2px;
}
#sidebar-housing {
 width: 300px;
 height: 600px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.62) 100%);
}
#sidebar-housing h1 {
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-family: abril-fatface;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 35px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#sidebar-housing p {
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
#container-care {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(images/tegucare.jpg);
}
#sidebar-care {
 width: 300px;
 height: 600px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.62);
}
h1 {
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-family: abril-fatface;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
p {
 color: #dfdfdf;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
#Accordion1 {
 width: 400px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 font-size: small;
 height: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 30px;
 left: 1px;
 top: -1px;
}
#container-media {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-image: url(images/media.jpg);
}
#sidebar-media {
 width: 300px;
 height: 450px;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.62);
}
#media {
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
#container-contact {
 width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-image: url(images/mushu-contact.jpg);
 clear: both;
}
#sidebar-contact {
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.62);
 clear: right;
}
#contact-form {
 width: 300px;
 height: 0400px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contact</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container-contact">
  <div id="sidebar-contact">
    <p>Mushu Loves Email</p>
    <p>Have something to say? We'd love to hear your comments, stories, and questions.</p>
    <p>Do you have pictures of your pet lizard you'd like to share or an experience with your tegu that you think was cool? Did you just get a tegu or are you thinking about getting a tegu? Have questions about husbandry or care that we haven't covered on this site? Do you just want to shoot the breeze?</p>
    <p>Just use the contact form to the right to send us an email. We'd love to hear from you.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="contact-form">
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="housing.html">housing</a></li>
        <li><a href="care.html">care</a></li>
        <li><a href="media.html">media</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for one, relatively positioning an element `670px` from the top may set it to the the bottom of your screen but there are many larger size screens to account for. Can you upload like an image or something to show what the desired result should be?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The desired result is for the menu to reside at the bottom of the container tag.  This has become more accidemnic as I had to turn in my work already but I am curious to know how I could have done this better.  The website is published at http://triosdevelopers.com/c.angerstein/final/